# Reading values from a custom ribbon edit box

Tags: excel, xml, vba

After a few hours of searching last night I've decided to give up and ask for help.  I'm trying to store a value from a Custom UI EditBox in a string when the user presses a button and I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the XML for the ribbon

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
<ribbon startFromScratch="false"> 
<tabs> 
  <tab id="CustomTab" label="My Tab"> 
    <group id="SimpleControls" label="My Group"> 
      <button id="Button1" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" 
              label="Large Button" 
              screentip="my long description" 
              onAction="MyMacro"/> 
      <editBox id="valueInput" label="Value" getText="getValue" screentip="A test control!."/>
    </group> 
  </tab> 
</tabs> 
</ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

Here is the VBA code in module1

```
Option Explicit

Public tmpVal As String

Public Function MyMacro(ByRef control As Office.IRibbonControl) As Long
'Call MsgBox("Hello large button")
Call getValue
Call MsgBox(tmpVal)
MyMacro = 1
End Function


Public Sub getValue(ByRef control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByRef text As String)
        tmpVal = text
End Sub
```

Running my macro without trying to call getValue works as expected and can produce a message box displaying the text "Hello large button". Running the code as it gives me the "Argument not optional error", but if I am understanding callback functions correctly those are supposed to be supplied by excel at runtime.  What am I missing?

EDIT: Fixed the name of a function call that was left over from a previous revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `onChange` callback and not the `getText` callback ie the relevant line of your RibbonX should be

```
<editBox id="valueInput" label="Value" onChange="getValue" screentip="A test control!."/>
```

... your VBA code looks fine (assuming `getHwnd` is present somewhere in your project as you haven't shared it in the code in the question).

For reference, the RibbonX EditBox docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/7b552756-a970-466d-b7c2-ee5bbe171e34) which clarify that:

- onChange - "called when the text in the control has been changed by the user"
- getText - "called to determine the text that SHOULD be displayed in the control"

Comment: How silly of me to assume that a function called getText would "get" a value instead of setting a value.  :)